# Vagrant up Segfault error

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

I would really like to use vagrant to set up a rails dev environment on my computer, but whenever i run vagrant up i get a segfault error. I have tried reinstalling both vagrant and virtualbox, and different versions of both. I'm new to vagrant and can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. Here is the error message:

```
F:\Projects\toy_app>vagrant up
C:/Users/JT/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/childprocess-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/han
dle.rb:44: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0036 p:---- s:0198 e:000197 CFUNC  :get_exit_code
c:0035 p:0035 s:0193 e:000192 METHOD C:/Users/JT/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/childproce
ss-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/handle.rb:44
c:0034 p:0029 s:0188 e:000187 METHOD C:/Users/JT/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/childproce
ss-0.5.6/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:41
c:0033 p:0716 s:0183 e:000182 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:160
c:0032 p:0013 s:0161 e:000160 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb:22
c:0031 p:0024 s:0156 e:000155 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:404
c:0030 p:0014 s:0154 e:000153 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19
c:0029 p:0039 s:0150 E:001408 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:403
c:0028 p:0017 s:0144 e:000143 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:342
c:0027 p:0044 s:0141 e:000140 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17
c:0026 p:0082 s:0135 e:000134 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb:337
c:0025 p:0009 s:0127 e:000126 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:141
c:0024 p:0044 s:0125 e:000124 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17
c:0023 p:0035 s:0119 e:000118 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:140
c:0022 p:0044 s:0114 e:000113 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/meta.rb:38 [FINISH]
c:0021 p:---- s:0107 e:000106 CFUNC  :new
c:0020 p:0019 s:0104 e:000103 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb:11
c:0019 p:0010 s:0100 e:000099 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:378 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0094 e:000093 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0249 s:0091 E:001c50 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:377
c:0016 p:0131 s:0081 e:000080 LAMBDA C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:165 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0075 e:000074 CFUNC  :call
c:0014 p:0108 s:0071 e:000069 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0065 e:000064 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0216 s:0062 E:0021f8 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174
c:0011 p:0072 s:0050 E:001580 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:74
c:0010 p:0008 s:0045 e:000044 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:277 [FINISH]
c:0009 p:---- s:0042 e:000041 CFUNC  :tap
c:0008 p:0017 s:0039 e:000038 BLOCK  C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:275 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0037 e:000036 CFUNC  :synchronize
c:0006 p:0032 s:0034 e:000033 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:274
c:0005 p:0114 s:0030 E:00110c METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:58
c:0004 p:0158 s:0023 e:000022 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42
c:0003 p:0020 s:0017 e:000016 METHOD C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:301
c:0002 p:0807 s:0013 E:001648 EVAL   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vag
rant-1.7.1/bin/vagrant:174 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0013fc TOP    [FINISH]
```

Then it goes on to list ~450 lines of backtrace.

Comment: Do you have an instance of vagrant at this path?

Comment: Yes, i do have vagrant in that path.

Comment: Does `vagrant provision` fail too?

Comment: Yes it also fails, but it fails at lib.rb instead of handle.rb

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a vagrant issue and more of a library incompatibility. See if this helps: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4202

Comment: Ah, thank you my friend. There must have been something wrong with my vagrant.d directory, deleting it and reinstalling did the trick.

Comment: Deleting .vagrant.d and reinstalling Vagrant did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it works for me.

`vagrant plugin uninstall ffi && vagrant plugin install ffi --plugin-version 1.9.8`

Comment: I was just about to update this, beaten! +1 for the solution it resolved the issues my colleague and I were seeing.

Comment: Simply deleting .vagrant.d in our case only seemed to solve the problem, it resurfaced relativly fast -- but this ffi-plugin manipulation does the trick for now.

Comment: I didn't have ffi plugin installed but installing the 1.9.8 version solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed *.vagrant.d* file. I was using Linux Mint-17. So I run this command 
`rm -r .vagrant.d/`.

I worked for me.